# find number of idling processor cores in Erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir

I need to find whether they are any idling processor cores and how much of them?

My task: I need to do a calculation in parallel and the number of processes which are running at a time need to be limited and not exceeding the existing number of processor cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This line](https://bitbucket.org/fenollp/brocessing/src/f6f5d70297d25dcf6245056450ef668aff829799/src/stateless.erl?at=master#cl-62) will give you the existing number of processor cores.

The rest of the code does pretty much what you intend to do anyway.

[Here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info_schedulers_online)'s the doc for that func call.

Comment: The documentation string for your function is wrong.